# PHP function don't return data. Shows ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

```
include("include/session.php");

    class createcountdown
        {
        public $start;
        public $howlong;
        public function get(){
        $this->start = $session->start; // $session->start Returns data from Mysql: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        $this->howlong = $session->howlong; // $session->howlong Returns data from Mysql: 300
        $diff = $this->start-3600 + $this->howlong-time();

        if($this->start + $this->howlong > time()){
           list($h,$min,$sec)=explode(":",date("H:i:s",$diff));
           $sum = $this->start + $this->howlong-time();
           return $sum;
        }
    }

    $obj = new createcountdown();
    $result = $obj->get();
    echo $result;
```

Comment: Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_FUNCTION' in cd.php on line 24

Comment: seems like you forget to close `}` on class declaration ... @Alex JL add that back for you

Comment: It's missing a closing brace. When I paste this code in to the interpreter, and add the brace, I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in php shell code on line 17"

Comment: Yeah, where is the brace supposed to go? It looks like it is missing after the `if` in `get()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using properties of undefined variable `$session`:

```
$this->start = $session->start;
$this->howlong = $session->howlong;
```

If it is global object use `global $session;` before accessing it.

Comment: Okey, but where I must to place: global $session; ?

Comment: Make it the first line of your get() function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is the missing brace after the `if` in `get()`.

When I add a brace after `list($h,$min,$sec)=explode(":",date("H:i:s",$diff));`, the code runs without an error.

Answer (score 0):

Please close class `}` operator missiong

```
include("include/session.php");

    class createcountdown
        {
        public $start;
        public $howlong;
        public function get(){
        $this->start = $session->start; // $session->start Returns data from Mysql: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        $this->howlong = $session->howlong; // $session->howlong Returns data from Mysql: 300
        $diff = $this->start-3600 + $this->howlong-time();

        if($this->start + $this->howlong > time()){
           list($h,$min,$sec)=explode(":",date("H:i:s",$diff));
           $sum = $this->start + $this->howlong-time();
           return $sum;
        }
    }
 }

    $obj = new createcountdown();
    $result = $obj->get();
    echo $result;
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: session in line 11

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object in line 12

Comment: class createcountdown
        {
           global $session;

Comment: parse error, expecting `T_FUNCTION' in line 6: class createcountdown { global $session;

Comment: class createcountdown
        {
        public $start;
        public $howlong;
        public function get(){   global $session;

Comment: Ooo, nice :) But its doest return data, just white page...?

Comment: if(($this->start + $this->howlong) > time()){
           list($h,$min,$sec)=explode(":",date("H:i:s",$diff));
           $sum = $this->start + $this->howlong-time();
           return $sum;
        } else return 0;

Comment: I'm in, dead end, I need this countdown timer for my browser game, but I can't, make it work :( Maybe you know, someone who have construction script?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
include("include/session.php");

    class createcountdown
        {
        public $start;
        public $howlong;
        public $session; // add 
        public function get(){
       // $this->start = $session->start; // $session->start Returns data from Mysql: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
         $this->start = $this->session->start; // change here
        // $this->howlong = $session->howlong; // $session->howlong Returns data from Mysql: 300
        $this->howlong = $this->session->howlong; // change here

        $diff = $this->start-3600 + $this->howlong-time();

        if($this->start + $this->howlong > time()){
           list($h,$min,$sec)=explode(":",date("H:i:s",$diff));
           $sum = $this->start + $this->howlong-time();
           return $sum;
        }
    }
 }

    $obj = new createcountdown();
    $obj->session = $session // which is globaly define
    $result = $obj->get();
    echo $result;
```